# I am getting 404 NOT FOUND error while using xhr simple POST opeartion

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Here I am doing simple file select operation and will upload to server in specify the path

```js
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = this.files[0];

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    (xhr.upload || xhr).addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        var done = e.position || e.loaded
        var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
        console.log('xhr progress: ' + Math.round(done/total*100) + '%');
    });
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        console.log('xhr upload complete', e, this.responseText);
    });
    xhr.open('post', '/Users/Documents/uploads/', true);
 
    var data = new FormData;
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('json', '{"foo":"bar"}'); // for jsFiddle
    xhr.send(data);
});
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" />
```

Comment: `XHR` can't be done on your local computer you need a server.

Comment: i tried in my server its not working there to